Extracting outer HTML of a tag using Puppeteer
I am newbie scraping and most specially new using Puppeteer.
I wanted to scrape a content from a website.
This is just a sample HTML
<section>
    <article>
        <div id="novel_content">
            <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer scelerisque, turpis a lobortis fringilla, nulla odio ultrices metus, eu eleifend nibh metus iaculis magna. Praesent vel euismod velit</p>
            <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer scelerisque, turpis a lobortis fringilla, nulla odio ultrices metus, eu eleifend nibh metus iaculis magna. Praesent vel euismod velit<br>
<img src="/images/imagefile.png"></p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer scelerisque, turpis a lobortis fringilla, nulla odio ultrices metus, eu eleifend nibh metus iaculis magna. Praesent vel euismod velit</p>
        </div>
    </article>
</section>

I manage to get the content already using the following
document.querySelector('article > div#novel_content > div').textContent;

But apparently this only gets the text content, it doesn't include the image src.
My expected result would be like this.
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer scelerisque, turpis a lobortis fringilla, nulla odio ultrices metus, eu eleifend nibh metus iaculis magna. Praesent vel euismod velit</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer scelerisque, turpis a lobortis fringilla, nulla odio ultrices metus, eu eleifend nibh metus iaculis magna. Praesent vel euismod velit<br><img src="/images/imagefile.png"></p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer scelerisque, turpis a lobortis fringilla, nulla odio ultrices metus, eu eleifend nibh metus iaculis magna. Praesent vel euismod velit</p>


Hi Oli, just to clarify you want to know how to get the image src from your example? The question part is quite unclear as it stands.

@MarcoGeertsma i basically wanted to get the whole content inside the including the html tags suchs as ,, or anything html tags inside the said 

Have you tried removing the .textContent from your current selector?

i did and i got responce  this actually from an actual page. because i did not include some of the content. I usually use wget for webscraping and I manage to get the whole HTML and pages.

I already figure it out. I'm not sure if I should post the whole code with the answer but anyway it was solves by using this code.  const data = await page.evaluate(() =>
document.querySelector('article > div#novel_content > div:nth-child(2)').outerHTML
);
